# Swift: Process() : Cannot find type Process in Scope

Tags: swift

I am trying to run a bash command from swift and for some reason I can't seem to use Process(). I get the error that type Process could not be found in Scope. I also tried importing couple of plugins to help with commandline execution and I get the same error. Below is the error from the plugin

[image]

Sample code that I tried

```
func run(_ cmd: String) -> String? {
    let pipe = Pipe()
    let process = Process()
    process.launchPath = "/bin/sh"
    process.arguments = ["-c", String(format:"%@", cmd)]
    process.standardOutput = pipe
    let fileHandle = pipe.fileHandleForReading
    process.launch()
    return String(data: fileHandle.readDataToEndOfFile(), encoding: .utf8)
}
```

Comment: @Cristik, sorry about that. I was connected to the mac remotely. I've updated the code now. The problem is, I cannot really use Process(). Not sure if this is replaced with some other method or deprecated.

Comment: Make sure on xcode you select "My Mac" as a destination

Answer (score 0):

If you’re using an old version of Xcode try to put NSProcess()

Comment: Thanks, Paolo. But, import Foundation is already added. But Process() isn't there in the Foundation library. I am not quite able to figure out as to why this is missing.

Comment: I added one solution

Comment: Thanks Paolo. I am on the latest version of Xcode (13.4.1) I think Process() is available only when building the project for platform -macOS. This is not available when the project is built for platform iOS. I just wanted to capture the logs from the process 'bluetoothd' of the phone. I wanted to integrate this with the automation workflow as a 2nd layer of validation wherein we look for certain BT specific events in the logs. There is idevicesyslog for this from libimobiledevice which needs to be triggered via bash/command line. Seems like there is no easy way via swift (For iOS)